# Python How many times each meta keyword is used in a string

Tags: python

I am trying to print out meta keywords from a website using site url then print out how many times each keyword has been used inside the article. I have written below code to extract meta keyword first from the url

```
 res = requests.get(
  'https://www.wpbeginner.com/showcase/24-must-have-wordpress-plugins-for-business-websites/',
   headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"}
 )

 response = res
 doc = Document(response.content)
 #doc.title()
 #print(doc.summary())
 soup = BeautifulSoup(doc.summary(), features='lxml')
 soup1 = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html5lib')
 text =  soup.get_text()

 meta_keywords = [item['content'] for item in soup1.select('[name=Keywords][content], [name=keywords][content]')]
 for mword in meta_keywords:
   print(mword)
```

Above code is printing out the meta keywords as comma separated value like

```
best wordpress plugins,wordpress business websites,wordpress plugins for business websites,wordpress tools for businesses
```

Now I am trying to fetch how many times each keyword is used inside the whole body text or article. I have tried below code but not working

```
for mword in meta_keywords:
x = text.count(mword)
print(mword,x)
```

it is printing out a result like below, a 0(zero) in the last, I think It is considering althose comma separated keywords as one word. don't know how to solve this

```
best wordpress plugins,wordpress business websites,wordpress plugins for business websites,wordpress tools for businesses 0
```

Comment: can you share the `text` paragraph. your code seems right to me..!

Comment: print(text) prints out the all text of above url

Comment: can you add the content `print(text)` in the question

Comment: print(text) is printing out all the article text of above url specified, However I found One Problem in my count loop it is taking all those comma separated keywords as one word I think as it is returning zero. I have edited the question pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:-**

```
#mword is like this yes
mword=["best wordpress plugins,wordpress business websites,wordpress plugins for business websites,wordpress tools for businesses 0"]
#Whole content
text="We are often asked by readers for the best wordpress plugins suggestions for SEO, social media, backups, speed, etc."
#converting into a string
temp=""
temp+=mword[0]
#converting string temp into a list
lis=list(temp.split(','))
print(lis)
for word in lis:
    print("Frequency of ["+word+"] : "+str(text.count(word)))
    break
```

**Output:-**

```
['best wordpress plugins', 'wordpress business websites', 'wordpress plugins for business websites', 'wordpress tools for businesses 0']
Frequency of [best wordpress plugins] : 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250458/discussion-on-answer-by-yash-mehta-python-how-many-times-each-meta-keyword-is-us).